# Rolling back transactions within stored procedures in Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions

I am new to using Transact-SQL, and I have a question on how transactions within nested stored procedures would be handled.

Consider the following example, where we create an example table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE_TABLE 
(
     ID INT, 
     NAME VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Then, we create a stored procedure with no parameters. This stored procedure involves inserting values into the table from above.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TABLE (ID, NAME) 
        VALUES (1, 'BOB')

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END;
```

And then we create a second stored procedure with one parameter that calls our first stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp2 
    @EXAMPLE INT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        EXEC SP1

        IF (@EXAMPLE < 10) 
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
        ELSE 
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END;
```

And then we call our second stored procedure as follows:

```
EXEC sp2 @EXAMPLE = 5;
```

At the end of this execution, will the values have been added to the `EXAMPLE_TABLE`? Or does the rollback in the outer stored procedure mean that everything has been rolled back, and nothing committed?

Comment: Suggested reading: [Transactions: Rolling back a nested transaction](https://sqlstudies.com/2013/12/17/transactions-rolling-back-a-transaction/).

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are scoped, so anything within a transaction is committed/rolled back together. So a value of 5 on your `@example` variable would prevent records from being added to the `EXAMPLE_TABLE`. You can check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e6f7e) for a demo.

I will add that if this example is in anyway similar to actual code you'll be writing, I would suggest to just check the variable value and make a decision on whether or not to run the insert stored procedure in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion of Aaron's answer is correct, but the reasoning is a little misleading.

Transactions aren't really "scoped" in the usual way you would think of scoping. The outermost `begin tran` does of course begin a transaction. But any nested `begin tran` doesn't really do anything other than increment the `@@trancount`. Then, when you `commit`, this doesn't really commit anything unless `@@trancount` is 1. Only the outermost `commit` is a "real" `commit`. Finally, a `rollback` will rollback *everything*, not just the current, "most nested" transaction, returning `@@trancount` to 0. At that point, if you try to `commit` or `rollback` you will get an error:

```
begin tran
print @@trancount
begin tran
print @@trancount
rollback
print @@trancount
commit


1
2
0
Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Line 61
The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.
```

For this reason, as a stylistic guide when actually coding transactions, I strongly suggest *not* treating a `begin tran` as the start of a block which needs to be indented. Treat `begin tran`, `commit` and `rollback` as regular statements, not the start and end of blocks.

The only exception to this behaviour is when you begin a named transaction, in which case you can rollback to the start of that named transaction.